# Changing to color of a JToggleButton only when the button is selected, afterwards it will go back to the default color

Tags: java

This may end up being noted as a formerly asked question, however the other questions have yet to answer the question that I have asked properly, to what I need them to do.
I want it to be that whenever I click the ToggleButton it will set the color of the ToggleButton to black (in this case), and then when I unclick the button it will return to the default color.

Here is the code for the individual button, its possible Ill have to create a new class (I am using Eclipse) but if anyone could help id be extremely thankful. (I also have Jigloo)

```
jToggleButton4 = new JToggleButton();
                getContentPane().add(jToggleButton4);
                FlowLayout jToggleButton4Layout = new FlowLayout();
                jToggleButton4.setLayout(jToggleButton4Layout);
                jToggleButton4.setText("Black");
                jToggleButton4.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(133, 249));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take the default color/ the color you keep initially and can toggle the background color with an `ActionEvent`,

```
JToggleButton jtb = new JToggleButton("My Button");
Color defaultColor=jtb.getBackground();

jtb.addActionListener(new ActionListener( ) {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                if(jtb.getBackground()==defaultColor)
                    jtb.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                else
                    jtb.setBackground(defaultColor);
                repaint();//repaint your frame
                System.out.println("BackGround color changed!");
              }
            });
```